# MySQL update single table with join

Tags: mysql

I have a values in table "REVIEW" that need to change REVIEW_STATUS from "UNDER_REVIEW" to "Abstain" based upon other records in the table that have the same REFERENCE_NUMBER , A specific REVIEW_TYPE and that REVIEW_STATUS is "ABSTAIN".  The I have a sample set up in SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8227f/1

I am able to query the tables for the records, but I am having difficulty getting the update query correct.

```
-- run   
UPDATE TABLE REVIEW AS REV1  
LEFT JOIN REVIEW AS REV2 
ON (REV1.REFERENCE_NUMBER=REV2.REFERENCE_NUMBER)
SET REV1.REVIEW_STATUS='ABSTAIN' 
WHERE 
REV1.REVIEW_TYPE ='QOC' 
AND 
REV1.REVIEW_STATUS='UNDER_REVIEW'
AND 
REV2.REVIEW_TYPE ='MED_NEC'
AND (REV2.REVIEW_STATUS ='ABSTAIN' )
;
```

Your help is appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: There's no reason to use a `LEFT JOIN` if you're looking for specific values in the table you're joining with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
UPDATE TABLE REVIEW AS REV1 
...
```

to

```
UPDATE REVIEW AS REV1 
...
```

Updated **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c11b/1)**

Answer (score 0):

It was the word TABLE

```
UPDATE  REVIEW AS REV1  
LEFT JOIN REVIEW AS REV2 
ON (REV1.REFERENCE_NUMBER=REV2.REFERENCE_NUMBER)
SET REV1.REVIEW_STATUS='ABSTAIN' 
WHERE 
REV1.REVIEW_TYPE ='QOC' 
AND 
REV1.REVIEW_STATUS='UNDER_REVIEW'
AND 
REV2.REVIEW_TYPE ='MED_NEC'
AND (REV2.REVIEW_STATUS ='ABSTAIN' )
;
```